# Math Subject exam 9768 Q.4

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

The question is given in the following picture[image]:

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Maybe find the intersection of $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ then calculate the area of the middle region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly evaluate each integral and solve for the unknown constant $b$.

The following is given:

$$\int_0^bxdx=\int_0^bx^2dx$$

So:

$$\int_0^bxdx=\bigg[\frac {x^2}{2}\bigg]^b_0=\frac {b^2}{2}$$
$$\int_0^bx^2dx=\bigg[\frac {x^3}{3}\bigg ]^b_0=\frac {b^3}{3}$$

So equate each evaluation and solve for $b$:

$$\frac {b^3}{3}=\frac {b^2}{2}\implies 2b^3-3b^2=0\implies b^2(2b-3)=0$$
$$\therefore b=0, \frac 32$$

$b= 0$ is the trivial case, and thus the only relevant value is $b=\frac 32$.

The equivalent function can be determined by equating each separate equality and solving for its roots.

Thus we have:

$$x^2=x\implies x^2-x=0\implies x(x-1)=0$$

$$\therefore x=0,1$$

The area bounded by the curves $y=x$ and $y=x^2$, as denoted by the above graph, can be determined by taking the integral of $f(x)=x^2-x$ on the closed interval $[1,\frac 32]$.

$$\int^b_1(x^2-x)dx=\bigg[\frac {x^3}{3}-\frac {x^2}{2}\bigg]^{\frac 32}_1=\frac {(\frac 32)^3}{3}-\frac {(\frac 32)^2}{2}-\bigg(\frac 13-\frac 12\bigg)=\frac 98-\frac 98-\frac 13+\frac 12=\frac 16$$

As we can clearly see, this is equivalent to $\int_0^1(x-x^2)dx$. This is due to the initial condition stated at the very top.

Comment: It is not clear for me why u took the integral from 1 to $3/2$?

Comment: Well, because both curves intersect each other at the point $(1,1)$, and we're only interested with the area bounded by each function beyond the point $x=1$ up to $b=3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: with these conditions, you can do it without finding the vertical line, and show the answer is equal to $$\int_0^1 x-x^2 dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The shaded region is equal to

$$\int_0^1x-x^2dx$$

Can you identify the region that corresponds to that integral?

Comment: yes, I can , but why the upper bound is 1?

Comment: We can divide the region into 3 pieces, the first part is the region bounded above by $y=x$ and bounded below by $y=x^2$, call the area $A$. The second region is the region bounded above by $y=x^2$ and bounded below by $y=x$ and bounded on the right by $x=b$, call the area $B$. the last region is the region above by $y=min(x,x^2)$, bounded below by $x$-axis and bounded on the right by $x=b$, call that area $C$. Try to write an equation linking $A$, $B$, and $C$.